# FFmpeg loading tracker files

Tags: ffmpeg

So, after poking around a bit, I discovered that ffmpeg may have the ability to load tracker files (like *.mod, *.xm *.it *s3m et cetera) via the power of [libopenmpt](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#libopenmpt).

The question is, how do I do this if it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a `ffmpeg` binary that has support for libopenmpt, or the older but buggier libmodplug; refer to the [FFmpeg Download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) for links. Otherwise, you'll have to compile it.

1. Get the `ffmpeg` source code.
2. Install libopenmpt.
3. Install any other needed dependencies.
4. Compile `ffmpeg` ensuring you include `--enable-libopenmpt` when you run `configure`.

You did not include any information about your system, so you'll have to adapt one of the guides at [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).